# Não consigo converter app rails de sqlite para postgres (para deploy heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho tentado fazer a conversão de um *app Rails* em sqlite para postgres afim de upa-lo no heroku, seguindo este tutorial do próprio heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Só que quando vou criar um DB usando o `rake db:create`, tenho essa mensagem de erro:

> rake db:create
>
> FATAL: role "caiograco" não existe

("caiograco" é o meu nome de usuário no Linux. Não sei como foi para ai)

Comment: Role é como é tratado um usuario no Postgresql. Se voce não definir o usuario no momento que executar `psql` ele entende que é para usar o usuario que o executou. Você deve passar a informação de usuario *dono* ou que possua *permissao* sobre a base.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8639649/1518921) você deve  adicionar o *nome de usuário* para o seu `database.yml`, poderia muito bem usar o nome do seu aplicativo (ou alguma variante do nome) como o nome de usuário, eu vou usar `app_name` como um espaço reservado:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: app_name
  password:
```

Também deve criar o mesmo usuário do "role" no PostgreSQL using psql:

```
$ psql -d postgres
postgres=# create role app_name login createdb;
postgres=# \q
```

A primeira linha é executada no seu terminal, as seguintes são dentro do postgres. Então após isto tente executar o `rake db:create`.